# I dont know why my localization is not working

Tags: plugins, translation, localization

I am working on a Plugin for Wordpress and I'm not able to get the Internationalization working.

Here is the GitHub Link: https://github.com/dev-nm/WP-StudioLink-Integration

I used wppb.me as a Boilerplate and titan framework as a Admin Panel Framework.
I created the pot, po and mo with poedit + Loco Translate (Cause I only have the free versio of poedit).

The following is happening:
In the Plugins Menue the translated short description is shown. In my own Menue none of the Strings is translated.

Structure for Translation is the following:

- studio-link-integration.php => `new Studio_Link_Integration` ( /includes/class-studio-link-integration.php )
- `__contruct => set_locale();`

  ```
  private function set_locale() {

  $plugin_i18n = new Studio_Link_Integration_i18n();
  $plugin_i18n->set_domain( 'studio-link-integration' );

  $this->loader->add_action( 'plugins_loaded', $plugin_i18n, 'load_plugin_textdomain' );

  }
  ```
- in class `Studio_Link_Integration_i18n`

  ```
  public function load_plugin_textdomain() {

  load_plugin_textdomain(
      $this->domain,
      false,
      dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages'
  );

  }
  ```

Language Files are in */languages/* and are named *studio-link-integration-de_DE*.

translation is done with *`__( 'Text to Translate', 'studio-link-integration' )`*.

I really dont know, why it wont work. Can someone look at my Files and help me? Am I forgetting some new specifications for translating? I read the whole Codex about Localization and Internationalisation but havent found anything new out that helped me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please give an example of an actual string that doesn't work. Your German file contains a lot of translations in English including your [main menu items](https://github.com/dev-nm/WP-StudioLink-Integration/blob/master/languages/studio-link-integration-de_DE.po#L21-L27).

Comment: Well, none of the Strings works. The only Text that apperas in German is the short description, but it gets loaded in another way I guess, cause it is translated even before activationg the Plugin. EDIT: I just read the Translation File. The short description is not translated there.

Comment: **EDIT**: Nevermind the EDIT of the Commentabove. I just fergot to update the Files in the GitHub. Just uploaded it now

Comment: **These Translations work:** [LINK](https://github.com/dev-nm/WP-StudioLink-Integration/blob/81213a66f3d97571f3882607b1e91076ea487132/languages/studio-link-integration-de_DE.po#L272-L290)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is [here](https://github.com/dev-nm/WP-StudioLink-Integration/blob/81213a66f3d97571f3882607b1e91076ea487132/includes/class-studio-link-integration-i18n.php#L48)

The path to your bundled translations resolve to a `languages` folder inside the `includes` folder, which is one level down from where it actually is.

Try it with an extra `dirname` and you will target it correctly:

```
dirname( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/languages/'
```

Or to be a bit tidier:

```
plugin_basename( __DIR__.'/../languages' )
```

Comment: Tanks a lot! But now i see there is another Problem: the Titan Framework, I included into the Plugin does not load its localization. Do you have an Idea how to include it without editing the Source of the Framework?

Comment: It is located in `admin/titan-framework/languages`

Comment: You can filter on this. See WP docs for [load_textdomain_mofile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load_textdomain_mofile/)

Comment: I'm curious why you unaccepted my answer after [fixing the bug](https://github.com/dev-nm/WP-StudioLink-Integration/commit/364580a85041ed7f4fdaeceb06d82be6b93469ae).